# Instagram API access without developing an app

Tags: instagram

I want to use the Instagram API to get public data on the social reach of various music artists on the Instagram platform.

Having looked at the API documentation, it would appear that access to the API is dependent on having a mobile app product approved to go live with the required access permissions.

However, my end use case for the data is not an app. Is there any way that I can obtain an access token to use the Instagram API for public information without developing a such an app?

Note: I am aware of the '?__a=1' solution but want a more official solution with greater long term stability.

Comment: Contact Instagram directly for questions about appropriate use of their API. We're not Instagram licensing support.

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for your input. I have already attempted to contact Instagram directly, however they do not appear to offer support for such queries. Their developer support page explicitly points to SO for any API related questions, hence my post.